# Lower bound on dimension of representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Consider $G=SL_3(p)$ for $p$ a prime number and the subgroup $H$ of $G$ given by
$$H=\Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b \in k \Bigg\}.$$
I have shown that $H$ has only one conjugacy class and I need to use this to prove that any nontrivial representation of $G$ has dimension at least $p^2-1$. I am not sure how to do this. I know some upper bounds on $\chi(1)$ the dimension, but not how to obtain a lower one.

Comment: $H$ is abelian of order $p^2$, so it certainly has more than one conjugacy class.

Comment: I meant $H$ is conjugate in $G$, sorry. So any two elements in $A,B \in H$ satisfy $B=XAX^{-1}$ for some $X \in G$.

Comment: That is only true if $A,B \in H$ are not equal to the identity.

Comment: It would be more helpful to edit the question rather than to make corrections in comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a representation of $H$ and $g$ is an element in the normalizer $N_G(H)$ of $H$ in $G$, then we can define a new representation of $H$ on the vector space $V$ such that $$h\cdot v=ghg^{-1}\cdot v$$ for all $h\in H$ and all $v\in V$. Let us write it ${}^gV$.

It is easy to check that ${}^gV$ is simple iff $V$ is, and that ${}^gV$ is trivial iff $V$ is. In this way we obtain an action of the normalizer $N_G(H)$ on the set of irreps of $H$, and also on the set of non-trivial irreps of $H$.

It is easy to check that invertible matrices of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}t&0&0\\0&a&b\\0&c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ are in the normalizer $N_G(H)$, and using that that $N_G(H)$ acts by conjugation transitively on $H\setminus\{1\}$.

Now, as the normalizer $N_G(H)$ acts by conjugation transitively on $H\setminus\{1\}$ (which is what you meant to be the observation about these groups, if not what you wrote) you can show that the action of $N_G(H)$ on the set of non-trivial irreps of $H$ is also transitive.

Now suppose that $W$ is a $G$-rep, and let $W|_H$ be the restriction of $W$ to $H$. The map $w\in W|_H\mapsto g\cdot w\in {}^g(W|_H)$ is then an isomorphism of $H$-reps.

Using this you can show that if $W|_H$ contains a non-trivial $H$-irrep, then it contains all non-trivial $H$-irreps, and therefore its dimension is at least $p^2-1$, for this is the number of non-trivial $H$-irreps and they are all of dimension $1$.

Finally, you should show that the restriction of a non-trivial $G$-rep to $H$ is a non-trivial $H$-rep.

Comment: About the beginning of your answer, in the question $H$ is not a normal subgroup of $SL_3(p)$: the elements of $H \setminus \{1\}$ are conjugate but they do not form a single conjugacy class. (Consider e.g. transposes of the matrices.)

Comment: @spin, indeed. I was thinking about the elements that do normalize $H$, which are enogh to get a transitive action.